# Use Javascript to run Bash script in background

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bash

I currently have a project site ( interact.rdarellano.com ) which uses PHP forms to run Bash scripts on my webserver. I'm not happy with this PHP method because it reloads the site every time that the button is clicked.

I've read that Javascript may be able to handle this task in the background. I've never experimented with Javascript so I'm hoping to find somebody that can help me achieve this or guide me on how to set this up.

Comment: `it reloads the site every time that the button is clicked` - this is an problem with the client side - nothing you change on the server will change that - `event.preventDefault()` in your onsubmit is likely to fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

Read about JSON and AJAX. Start with Jquery which has methods to deal with this.